# Saving iOS Calendar Event is now giving an error

Tags: ios, runtime-error, ekevent, ekeventstore

```
Error pushing dirty properties for EKPersistentLocation to daemon: Error Domain=NSMachErrorDomain Code=4097 "unknown error code"
Connection interrupted!
```

Any ideas as to why I cannot save my events anymore?

```
    NSString *eventIdentifier = ...
    EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];
    EKEvent *event = [store eventWithIdentifier:eventIdentifier];
    if(event == nil) {
        event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
    }

    //fill event code here

    //save event
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
    if(error) {
        @throw error;
    }

    if(!success) {
        @throw [Error ERROR_EVENT_SYNC_FAILED_NO_ERROR];
    }
```

Interestingly, no error object is generated but success is NO. The error code and message are not particularly helpful. I am not sure what it means by dirty properties but I am not reusing an old event but grabbing one from the store or making a new one every time. I also do not know what Connection Interrupted means.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error.  It was caused by requesting access to events of type .event and trying to save a reminder.  If you are saving calendar entries as events then request access to .event if you are requesting access to reminders request access of type .reminder.
Below is an example of requesting access to reminders.

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            self.eventStore = EKEventStore()
            self.reminders = [EKReminder]()
            self.eventStore.requestAccess(to: .reminder, completion: requestAccessCompletionHandler)
        }

        func requestAccessCompletionHandler (granted: Bool, error: Error?) {
            NSLog("requestAccessCompletionHandler")
            if (granted) {

                let predicate = self.eventStore.predicateForReminders(in: nil)
                self.eventStore.fetchReminders(matching: predicate, completion: { (reminders: [EKReminder]?) -> Void in
                    self.reminders = reminders
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })
            } else {
                print("The app is not permitted to access reminders, make sure to grant permission in the settings and try again")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, the "dirty properties" refer to the EKEvent properties not being assigned the correct type. The "now gives an error" in the title was because that particular branch of code was not getting called due to a change and proper code before it was getting called.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of other people searching `NSMachErrorDomain Code=4097` in relation to EventKit, I recently started seeing this code when updating the `startDate` and `endDate` properties of a repeating event with a span of `.futureEvents`, but not committing the changes right away.

Calling:

`try eventStore.save(event, span: span, commit: false)`

and later when dismissing the edit screen:

`try eventStore.save(event, span: span, commit: true)`

The second call throws an error, does not commit the changes, and shows this output in the console:

`Month 13 is out of bounds
[EventKit] Failed to get melted object for frozen object related by key detachedItems. Event store is nil
[EventKit] Connection interrupted!
[CADXPCProxyHelper] Received error from calaccessd connection: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.calaccessd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.calaccessd}. Attempting to call any reply handler.
[EventKit] Error committing event store: [Error Domain=NSMachErrorDomain Code=4097 "unknown error code"]`

**Edit:** I found out that the real problem was that my initial call with `commit: false` was using `.futureEvents`, but my function wasn't updating the selected span, so the second call was defaulting to `.thisEvent`. It seems that this mismatch between the spans was causing the error.